# how to show 2d Array in html page with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanna show all Ingredient of each recipes, I created a 2d array and push each name of Ingredient of each recipe,  outputting all ingredient in console is no problem( console.log($scope.listOfIngredient[i][j].Ingredient.name) is working) ,but console.log($scope.listOfIngredient) doesn't work, which make me confused, and another thing is that listOfIngredient in html file just contains one random ingredient of recipe, as you see picture below code, browser always can only show one recipe Ingredient, but  console.log($scope.listOfIngredient) shows nothing in this listOfIngredient.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.listOfRecipe = null;
  var url = "http://164.132.196.117/chop_dev/recipe/recipes.json";
  var url2 = "http://164.132.196.117/chop_dev/recipe/recipes/view/";
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url

  }).then(function(response) {

    $scope.listOfRecipe = response.data.recipes;
    var recipeLength = $scope.listOfRecipe.length;

    $scope.listOfIngredient = new Array(recipeLength);

    console.log(recipeLength);
    for (var i = 0; i < recipeLength; i++) {
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url2 + response.data.recipes[i].Recipe.id + ".json"
      }).then(function(response2) {


        var IngredientLength = response2.data.recipe.IngredientMapping.length;
        console.log(IngredientLength);

        for (var j = 0; j < IngredientLength; j++) {
          $scope.listOfIngredient[i] = new Array(IngredientLength);
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < IngredientLength; j++) {
          $scope.listOfIngredient[i][j] = response2.data.recipe.IngredientMapping[j];

          console.log($scope.listOfIngredient[i][j].Ingredient.name);
          /*  $scope.listOfIngredient[i].push(response2.data.recipe.IngredientMapping[j]); */
        }
      });
    }
    console.log($scope.listOfIngredient);
  })
});
```

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController" class="center">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="ingredientMapping2" ng-repeat="recipes in listOfIngredient track by $index ">
      <ul>{{recipes}}</ul>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in recipes track by $index ">
          {{x.Ingredient.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: here is my browser output]

Comment: where is the issue? use chrome AngularJs plugin [batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) to look more into angular `$scope` instead of using `console.log()`

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log($scope.listOfIngredient);` does not work because it is outside of your inner `$http` request.

Rather than a 2D array, I would advise to modify your data structure like:

```
$scope.recipes = [
    { name: 'My Recipe',
        ingredients: [
            {name: 'Ingredient 1'},
            {name: 'Ingredient 2'}
        ]
    }
];
```

To list all recipes and each one's ingredients you would use a nested `ng-repeat`:

```
<ul class="recipes">
    <li class="recipe" ng-repeat="recipe in recipes">
        <span class="name">{{recipe.name}}</span>
        <ul class="ingredients">
            <li class="ingredient" ng-repeat="ingredient in recipe.ingredients">
                {{ingredient.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>  
</ul>
```

Another thing to note is that because you are using an async `$http` call inside your `for(var i=0; i<recipeLength;i++){...}` loop, that inside the response function the value of `i` may not be what you expect.  To avoid this, making the `$http` call from function that takes the index value as a parameter would keep the index local for that call.

If you use the structure I said, your loops would look something like:

```
function loadRecipe(Recipe){
    var RecipeEntry = {
        name: Recipe.name,
        ingredients: []
    };
    $scope.recipes.push(RecipeEntry};

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url2+ Recipe.id +".json"
    }).then(function (response2) {
        RecipeEntry.ingredients = response2.data.recipe.IngredientMapping;
    });
}

function loadRecipes(){
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url
    }).then(function (response) {
        var recipes = response.data.recipes;

        $scope.recipes = [];
        for(var i=0; i < recipes.length; i++){
            loadRecipe(recipes[i].Recipe);
        }
    });
}

loadRecipes();
```